# Jcarousel - добавить центральной картинке активный класс

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, как можно добавить центральной картинке активный класс? Отображение по 3 картинки.

Comment: Лисёнок, большое спасибо, работает!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Найти функцию которая меняет / отображает картинки и добавить в конец:

```
$('#div_id  img').removeClass('active');
$('#div_id  img:img:eq(1)').addClass('active');
```

Где

```
    $('#div_id  img').removeClass('active'); - убирает класс 'active' со всех изображений #div_id

    $('#div_id img:img:eq(1)') // выбирает из #div_id второе изображение

    .addClass('active'); // добавляет класс к изображению, в данном случае класс 'active'
```

Comment: C этим вроде ясно, найти бы теперь эту функцию))

Comment: next: function() {
                if (this.tail !== null && !this.inTail) {
                    this.scrollTail(false);
                } else {
                    this.scroll(((this.options.wrap == 'both' ||     this.options.wrap == 'last') && this.options.size !== null && this.last == this.options.size) ? 1 : this.first + this.options.scroll);
            }

         $('#div_id  img').removeClass('active');
         $('#div_id  img:img:eq(1)').addClass('active');
        },

Как то так.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ANmey/

Наш повторяющийся код хорошо бы вынести в функцию. Но это уже сами справитесь.

Comment: Почему-то не работает.. вообще класс не добавляет..

Comment: А если для li, то так?
$('#mycarousel li').removeClass('active');
$('#mycarousel li:li:eq(1)').addClass('active');

Comment: Если вот так:
$('#mycarousel li').removeClass('active');
$('#mycarousel li:eq(1)').addClass('active');

то:
добавляется,только при клике по next на второй элемент и там остается..

Comment: $('#mycarousel li').removeClass('active'); 
    $('#mycarousel li:eq(1)').addClass('active'); // тут 1 li 

Вообще легче было бы увидеть ссылку на сайт.

Comment: Проблема в том что элементов больше чем 3. Следовательно алгоритм примерно такой:

http://jsfiddle.net/ANmey/1/

Также в html коде пропишите класс active второму li #mycarousel чтобы скрипт мог определить активный элемент.